# No puedo mostrar los elementos de en mi vaddin-grid

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, vaadin

Estoy haciendo uso de vaadin-grid, donde tengo que mostrar una lista que es almacenada en `statusReservedList`, pero no muestra nada pese a que en la consola esta los resultados del arreglo, alguna idea para ver cual es el problema gracias.

```
<vaadin-grid theme="row-dividers" items="{{statusReservedList}}"  class="data-table-grid" column-reordering-allowed multi-sort height-by-rows>
                    <vaadin-grid-column width="5%">
                        <template class="header">
                            <vaadin-grid-sorter path="seat">[[localize('seat')]]</vaadin-grid-sorter>
                            <br/>
                            <vaadin-grid-filter path="seat"></vaadin-grid-filter>
                        </template>
                        <template>[[item.seat]]</template>
                    </vaadin-grid-column>

                    <vaadin-grid-column width="5%">
                        <template class="header">
                            <vaadin-grid-sorter path="floor">[[localize('floor')]]</vaadin-grid-sorter>
                            <br/>
                            <vaadin-grid-filter path="floor"></vaadin-grid-filter>
                        </template>
                        <template>[[item.floor]]</template>
                    </vaadin-grid-column>

                </vaadin-grid>
```

....
Metodo que carga esos elementos:
.....

```
_loadingInformationSheet: function () {
                this._findRouteReservationSheetInformation(this.routeId, this.date).then(function (_reservationInfo) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < _reservationInfo.floorsNumber; i++) {

                        var floorId = "floor_" + i;
                        var rowsField = floorId + "_rows";
                        var columnsField = floorId + "_columns";
                        var totalItemsLength = _reservationInfo[rowsField] * _reservationInfo[columnsField];

                        for (var j = 0; j < totalItemsLength; j++) {
                            var itemId = floorId + "_item_" + (j < 10 ? "0" + j : j);
                            var itemObj = _reservationInfo[itemId];
                            if (itemObj) {
                                var statusReservedListTmp = { seat: "", floor: "", passenger: "", documentType: "", state: "" };
                                statusReservedListTmp.floor = itemObj.label;
                                statusReservedListTmp.passenger = itemObj.passengerName;
                                statusReservedListTmp.documentType = itemObj.documentType;
                                statusReservedListTmp.state = itemObj.state;
                                this.statusReservedList.push(statusReservedListTmp);                  

                            }
                        }
                    }

                }.bind(this));
            },
```

Salida por consola:

**

```
**{seat: "", floor: 3, passenger: "FERNANDEZ, LUIS", documentType: "CI", state: "UNAVAILABLE"}
4
:
{seat: "", floor: 4, passenger: " MARIANA, LEONARDO", documentType: "CI", state: "UNAVAILABLE"}
5
:
{seat: "", floor: 5, passenger: "HERBAS, luis", documentType: "CI", state: "UNAVAILABLE"}**
```

**

Answer (score 0):

intenta hacer una notificación al componente. Esta dentro de una petición asíncrona por lo tanto Polymer nunca sabe que la variable ya cambio con tu datos.

Checa el `notifyPath` y los `arrayMutations`

[NotifyPath:Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/model-data#notifyPath)

[ArrayMutations](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/model-data#array-mutation)

Quedaría algo así:

```
         _loadingInformationSheet: function () {
            this._findRouteReservationSheetInformation(this.routeId, this.date).then(function (_reservationInfo) {
                for (var i = 0; i < _reservationInfo.floorsNumber; i++) {

                    var floorId = "floor_" + i;
                    var rowsField = floorId + "_rows";
                    var columnsField = floorId + "_columns";
                    var totalItemsLength = _reservationInfo[rowsField] * _reservationInfo[columnsField];

                    for (var j = 0; j < totalItemsLength; j++) {
                        var itemId = floorId + "_item_" + (j < 10 ? "0" + j : j);
                        var itemObj = _reservationInfo[itemId];
                        if (itemObj) {
                            var statusReservedListTmp = { seat: "", floor: "", passenger: "", documentType: "", state: "" };
                            statusReservedListTmp.floor = itemObj.label;
                            statusReservedListTmp.passenger = itemObj.passengerName;
                            statusReservedListTmp.documentType = itemObj.documentType;
                            statusReservedListTmp.state = itemObj.state;
                            this.push('statusReservedList', statusReservedListTmp);                  

                        }
                    }
                    this.notifyPath('statusReservedList', statusReservedList);
                }

            }.bind(this));
        }
```

Con eso debería funcionar sin broncas.

Saludos.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias, lo voy a probar y te comento